# ListBox Value to Date

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert a value from my `ListBox` string value to a `Date`.

The string looks like: "`Friday, 15 March 2015`" (Excel: long date)

How can I convert it to a normal date?
I tried `DateValue`, but it gives me an "`Type mismatch`" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reach your purpose in 2 steps; first, you need to get rid of the "day, " part of the string. Then, you can use the `Format` function to store your date into a `Date` type variable. Here's an example:

```
Dim myDate As Date
myString = "Sunday, 29 March 2015"
newDate = Format(Split(myString, ",")(1), "Short Date")
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, the main problem is that Short Date doesn't expect the "Friday, " so you need to remove it (either with this, a regex, or split: see @MatteoNNZ solution for the split)

```vb
Dim newDate as Date
newDate = Format(Right(oldDate, 14), "Short Date")
```

Comment: This would fail when the month is not 5 characters long and/or the day is not 2-digits. Examples of fails: "1 May 2014", "2 July 2012". It sticks to the fact that the input string is always 14 characters long.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Yep, was just about to add a split option when you added yours :). Actually, had the split originally but used [1] for array call and had to relook at (too many languages lately)